# How to compare two arrays of string?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I want to compare two string arrays. I don't know how to implement this in vb.net.

Let's say I have two arrays

```
Dim A() As String = {"Hello", "How", "Are", "You?")
Dim B() As String = {"You", "How", "Something Else", "You")
```

And I want to compare A() with B() to see how they are similar and different (The order of the elements does not matter, which means the program does not check the order of the elements and only compares if there are same elements).
Also the code would ignore the same elements in the same string array(like the second "You" in array B(). Then the code would return the elements these are same and the elements those are different. In this case the output message should be:

The same elements are "You" and "How"

The different element is "Something Else"

Comment: Are you expecting "You?" and "You" to be the same? and isn't "Hello" also a different element?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Linq` use `Except()` to find the differences between the two arrays and `Intersect()` to find which elements are in both arrays.

```
Imports System.Linq

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim A() As String = {"Hello", "How", "Are", "You?"}
        Dim B() As String = {"You", "How", "Something Else", "You"}

        Console.WriteLine("A elements not in B: " + String.Join(", ", A.Except(B)))
        Console.WriteLine("B elements not in A: " + String.Join(", ", B.Except(A)))
        Console.WriteLine("Elements in both A & B: " + String.Join(", ", A.Intersect(B)))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
A elements not in B: Hello, Are, You?
B elements not in A: You, Something Else
Elements in both A & B: How
```

Comment: Missing `.ToArray` ... `String.Join(", ", A.Except(B).ToArray)` ... by my opinion, best solution is this one by Shar1er80. Same with `String.Join(", ", A.Intersect(B).ToArray)`

Comment: @nelek You don't need ToArray() in the String.Join().  Except() returns an IEnumerable, which String.Join() can use.

Comment: I got this error without `.ToArray` : `Unable to cast object of type '<IntersectIterator>d__8b'1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'` ... ?? :(

Comment: @nelek Both of your variables are arrays?  That errors looks like your variable "B" is just a String and not a String array.

Comment: Yes, both are arrays. Like in bill example.

Comment: there is complete code I used (by this way everything is ok, but w/o .toArray not) `Dim A() As String = {"Hello", "How", "Are", "You"}
        Dim B() As String = {"Are", "You", "Something Else"}
        lblInfo.Text = "Same element(s) = " + String.Join(", ", A.Intersect(B).ToArray) + "<br>"
        lblInfo.Text += "Diff.element(s) = " + String.Join(", ", A.Except(B).ToArray) + ", " + String.Join(", ", B.Except(A).ToArray)`

Comment: @nelek Maybe it's the .NET framework you're referencing in your project.  String.Join() didn't accept an IEnumerable until 4.0.

Comment: @Shra1er80 ... then is ok... I use 3.5 :)

Comment: @nelek Then ToArray() is needed in your case.

Comment: @bill You're welcome.  If my answer helped solve your question, kindly click the check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq extensions. `Except` will tell you which items are different

```
' ones in A but not in B
Dim result() As String = A.Except(B).ToArray()

' ones in B but not in A
Dim result() As String = B.Except(A).ToArray()
```

[And you can use `Join` to find same items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534644%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Here is One method to find same items, or different items

```
Dim a() as string = {"a", "b", "c"}
Dim b() as string = {"a", "b", "z"}

Dim sameItems() as String = a.Where(Function(i) b.Contains(i)).ToArray()
Array.ForEach(sameItems, Sub(i) Console.WriteLine(i))    

Dim diffItems() as String = a.Where(Function(i) Not b.Contains(i)).ToArray()
Array.foreach(diffItems, Sub(i) Console.WriteLine(i))
```

And of course, you can use `Intersect`

Answer (score -1):

Set up a for loop and use .equals to compare each string at each element in the arrays. I can write the code if you need it.